# How to make Oracle return an error when i give it invalid SQL?

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net, odp.net-managed

I've been using the [Oracle ODP.NET, Managed Driver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/) to issue queries from C#.

There were many queries i wrote that took *forever* to return any data; like it was ignoring my row limiting clauses:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * 
FROM Customers
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

It was like Oracle was ignoring my **10** row limit, and started returning everything - because it was taking ***forever*** to return. Eventually i realized that it wasn't that the query was busy returning a lot of data; it was that the query SQL was invalid.

When you issue invalid SQL to Oracle, it will not fail with an error.

- `select top 10 * from customers;`
- `select 'Hello, world!';`
- `select sysdate from duel;`
- `select sysdate fro;`
- `Ceilings make pie and markers drive the ocean with their feet`

Oracle will sit there waiting for the command timeout to expire.

```
IDbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "Ceilings make pie and markers drive the ocean with their feet";

IDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); //<--will wait forever

while (rdr.Read()) 
{
   //...
}
```

I eventually realized that the `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand` object (*bizzarly*) has no `CommandTimeout`; it defaults to running forever. Once i changed it to a more reasonable 30 seconds, i start seeing the error message:

> ORA-12537: Network Session: End of file

Is there an option in the Oracle ODP.NET, Managed Driver, or in the connection string, or in the `OracleCommand` to tell the server to throw an error if there is an error in my SQL statement?

### Bonus Chatter

Oracle provides two database drivers for ADO.net

- one is an ADO.net managed wrapper around the 100MB native database drivers that you must already have installed (**Oracle.DataAccess**)
- the other is a standalone 3.8 MB driver, written in pure managed code, that has no other dependencies (**Oracle.ManagedDataAccess**)

Microsoft had created an Oracle driver, which is included in the .NET Framework. [But that driver is deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77d8yct7.aspx), and <strike>no longer functions in .NET 4.5</strike> requires the full Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater to be installed (**System.Data.OracleClient**)

Comment: You don't mention it, are you getting back data in a reasonable time with valid SQL?

Comment: Odd, I can't reproduce this.  The behaviour you are asking for (throw an exception if the SQL is invalid) is the behaviour I would expect of the driver, and is the behaviour I saw with all five of your invalid queries.  Do you get the same behaviour when you run invalid queries against the same database using another program, such as SQL*Plus?

Comment: @ShannonSeverance Yes i do. `SELECT 1 FROM Dual` returns instantly.

Comment: Do you have access to DB, ie. V$SESSION and v$sql? Which statement arrives the DB? See http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81/how-to-find-the-latest-sql-statements-within-the-database

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Unfortunately i don't have access to anything on the server; it's someone else's server, and i'm only issuing my read-only queries.